# I can't properly add external dependency with bazel

Tags: c++, googletest, bazel

I trying to test "Hello World" C++ project with Bazel.

I have the following project structure:

```
WORKSPACE
/dependencies
  BUILD
  BUILD.gtest
/test
  BUILD
```

WORKSPACE has the following structure:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

# gtest
http_archive(
    name = "gtest",
    url = "https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.10.0.zip",
    sha256 = "94c634d499558a76fa649edb13721dce6e98fb1e7018dfaeba3cd7a083945e91",
    build_file = "@//dependencies:BUILD.gtest",
    strip_prefix = "googletest-release-1.10.0",
)
```

BUILD.gtest has the following structure:

```
cc_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = glob(
        ["src/*.cc"],
        exclude = ["src/gtest-all.cc"]
    ),
    hdrs = glob([
        "include/**/*.h",
        "src/*.h"
    ]),
    copts = ["-Iexternal/gtest/include"],
    linkopts = ["-pthread"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

test BUILD has the following structure:

```
cc_test(
  name = "unittests",
  srcs = ["scanner_test.cc"],
  copts = ["-Iexternal/gtest/include"],
  deps = [
   "//scanner:scanner",
   "@gtest//:main"
  ]
)
```

when I execute

```
bazel build //test:unittests
```

I get

```
INFO: Analyzed target //test:unittests (26 packages loaded, 315 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: ../test/BUILD:1:8: Compiling test/scanner_test.cc failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF ... (remaining 25 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
test/scanner_test.cc:1:10: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "gtest/gtest.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Target //test:unittests failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.314s, Critical Path: 0.08s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: repository if needed https://github.com/gottlob96/ion-cpp/tree/external-dependency-problem

Comment: In bazel you do not deal with `-I` mess, because it is dirty and it does not work with sandboxing. Instead you should create separate bazel target (in that case is not needed, because gtest team done it already) and use `deps` attribute

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The file `BUILD.gtest` is not needed.

`WORKSPACE.bazel`:

```
workspace(name = "GTestDemo")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
  name = "gtest",
  url = "https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.10.0.tar.gz",
  sha256 = "9dc9157a9a1551ec7a7e43daea9a694a0bb5fb8bec81235d8a1e6ef64c716dcb",
  strip_prefix = "googletest-release-1.10.0",
)
```

`BUILD.bazel`:

```
cc_test(
    name = "tests",
    srcs = ["test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@gtest//:gtest",
        "@gtest//:gtest_main",
    ],
)
```

`test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

using namespace std;

TEST(sample_test_case, sample_test) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

Tested with Bazel `4.1.0`.

Comment: I used BUILD.gtest from [doc](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/external.html) to exclude gtest-all.cc but without custom build file all works fine. Thanks!

Comment: not working with that exact bazel version on OSX

Comment: Most probably you're utilizing somehting pertaining to your OS installation and do not rely og gtest just as external bazel dependency

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer mentions:

> The file `BUILD.gtest` is not needed.

Because gtest repo / release archive already provides one.

The reason why your own didn't behave as you might have expected is you've tried to point to the headers by manipulating [`copts`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.copts) which is applied only to building that one specific `cc_library` target (from linked docs):

> The flags take effect only for compiling this target, not its dependencies, so be careful about header files included elsewhere.

Whereas to expose these interfaces to other targets consuming it you need to use [`includes`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.includes) (docs again):

> Unlike COPTS, these flags are added for this rule and every rule that depends on it.

Comment: I use example from [docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/external.html) Changing copts to the includes didn't help, but thanks!

Comment: You would not need to just change `copts` to `includes`, but also make sure it points to the correct place, like the `gtest` target in the `BUILD` file in "their" repo: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/2f80c2ba71c0e8922a03b9b855e5b019ad1f7064/BUILD.bazel#L106-L111